# How to convert a sequence variable into a matrix in Scala

Tags: list, scala, matrix, type-conversion, scala-breeze

This should be easy, but I'm stuck. I'm trying to convert a `Seq[Seq[Double]]` type into a Breeze `DenseMatrix`. (all nested Seq[Double]'s have the same number of elements.)

Converting a single sequence to a `DenseVector` is pretty easy:

```
val sss=Seq(2.3,3.4,2.0,1.0)
val bbb=DenseVector(sss:_*)
```

Is there any similar approach to convert a `Seq[Seq[Double]]` type to a `DenseMatrix`? For example:

```
val sss=Seq(2.3,3.4,2.0,1.0)
val sssM=Seq(sss,sss,sss)
val bbb=DenseVector(sss:_*)
//val bbm= DenseMatrix(sssM:_*:??)  //????
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the same approach works fine:

```
val sss=Seq(2.3,3.4,2.0,1.0)
val sssM=Seq(sss,sss,sss)
val bbb=DenseVector(sss:_*)
val bbm= DenseMatrix(sssM:_*)
```

Initially I had thought that we need to expand each nested sequence as well. But as stated by Rex Kerr, in a comment below, the Breeze library automatically takes care of that.

Comment: It's not the compiler--the Breeze library companion object has been written with a method that does what you want.